# Unity doesn't start and reconfiguration fails

Tags: unity, compiz

I have a problem with unity that took me one day to approximatively solve. Approximatively means that it is not convenient and I need to fully fix the problem.

I have bought a [viper computer](http://www.materiel.net/ordinateur/materiel-net-viper-haswell-pc-gamer-99194.html). I installed Ubuntu 14.04. Everything went fine, though I had to install proprietary drivers to have a stable display (otherwise after 5 to 10 minutes the display start to show unreadable things.)

Last Thursday, I ran the (security) update and afterward (on Friday) unity didn't start anymore. I switched to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> terminal and tried many things, I also googled my problem.
For instance,

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && setsid unity
```

but this doesn't work (first error is asking for a display, so even running
`export DISPLAY=:0` before, it gives another error whose content seems to be put in the `.Xauthority` file of the home folder)

I finally noticed that removing the `~/.Xauthority` file and then running a gnome desktop afterward solve partially the problem. I can start unity and recover my usual desktop.
But after each restart my unity desktop still doesn't start and I have to start the gnome desktop.

What is happening with my unity ? Will I manage to have a stable desktop? (It is a professional computer I need something very stable)

```
Note: I checked with ccsm, unity is activated.
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `~/.config/compiz-1` directory (as suggested in [achiang's](http://askubuntu.com/a/77789/22949) and [dome cs's](http://askubuntu.com/a/73726/22949) answers to [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/22949))? Did you try [installing Unity Tweak Tool and running `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`](http://askubuntu.com/a/476656/22949)? If neither of these other possible solutions work (or for some reason you cannot or strongly prefer not to attempt them), I recommend [edit]ing your post with details. (And if one does fix it, great!)